# Log4net best practices to deal with multi tenancy (1 output file)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, log4net, multi-tenant

So my webapi solution works with multiple tenants and I want the logging to be something like this:

> 2018-05-09 11:06:00,490 ((tenantId)) [12] INFO method name - logs
>
> 2018-05-09 11:07:00,490 ((default value if call isn't on tenant level)) [12] warning method name - logs

My idea to solve the solution was to add the tenantId manually using

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["tenantId"] = tenantId;
```

But then again, I don't have access to tenantId on every level of the solution. I tried to add it in my base controller (which implements ApiController) looks like this

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext 
controllerContext)
{
    var tenantIdentifier = 
    requestUtils.GetTenantHeader(controllerContext.Request);
    if (tenantIdentifier != null)
       log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["tenantId"] = tenantIdentifier;
    else
       log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["tenantId"] = "default";
    await SetTenantIdentifier(tenantIdentifier);
    base.Initialize(controllerContext);
}
```

The issue with this idea is that for me setTenantId needs await but I can't make Initialize a Task (async) method.

Comment: Why does SetTenantIdentifier have to be async?

Comment: Are you using an IoC framework? I've worked on a solution like this before and injected a guid (tenant Id) using autofac which was scoped to the lifetime of the request.

Comment: I need to set the encryption key (which is per tenant) when setting the tenant, so to fetch it I need to make it async.

Comment: Perhaps the setting of the encryption key can be factored out

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I'm using Unity for IoC

Comment: Instead of encrypting your tenant ID you could let anyone pass any tenant ID, and simply check it against whatever membership schema you have (i.e. does this current user belong to this tenant), but I guess that's a bigger question of architecture. In terms of this requirement, take the tenant ID from the request and at your composition root inject it. At *that* point you can do whatever you need to with encryption.

Comment: I don't encrypt my tenant Id but I have an encryption key per tenant Id (to decrypt the data needed for this specific tenant)

Comment: Ok, I may be misunderstanding sorry, probably off-topic anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving `await SetTenantIdentifier(tenantIdentifier);` without calling `await`, yet it didn't work and `Log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["tenantId"] = tenantIdentifier;`
 would return null on the controller logs but worked in the base controller (because it was changing threads between calls)

> 2018-05-10 13:59:21,289 (tenant) [8] INFO 
>   - Base Controller - Tenant Identifier set to tenant
>
> 2018-05-10 13:59:21,504 ((null)) [12] INFO 
>   - Test Controller - Hi from controller

So I used `Log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["tenantId"] = tenantIdentifier;`
 instead of `Log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["tenantId"] = tenantIdentifier;`
 and it worked.

EDIT: I wrote ThreadContext in both lines but I meant that I used LogicalThreadContext instead of ThreadContext.

Comment: Sorry, what's the difference? But LogicalThreadContext may work.

Comment: @DylanNicholson Yeah it was a typo, thanks for notifying me!